# How can we set the poll configuration(polling the FTP server) in Spring Integration with FTP

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I am writing an application to connect to the FTP server to transfer files to my local machine.For this,I am using the Inbound Channel Adapter.Once,I start the application,I see that all the relevant files are getting transferred to my local directory from the FTP server until a time is reached when all the files are finally in sync(same number of files on both FTP server and local). I now want to poll the FTP server every 5 minutes to check for any new files present.I initially thought it would be the field 'fixed-rate' but it seems like it polls every 3 seconds to the FTP server.Am I missing something here?

My config file is as under:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="ftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${ftp.host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${ftp.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
                                     channel="ftpChannel"
                                     session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                                     filename-pattern="*.xml"
                                     auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                     delete-remote-files="false"
                                     remote-directory="/"
                                     local-directory="ftp-inbound"
                                     local-filter="acceptOnceFilter">

        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="-1">
            <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
        </int:poller>

    </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <bean id="acceptOnceFilter"
          class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter" />

    <int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
        <int:after-rollback expression="@acceptOnceFilter.remove(payload)" />
    </int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager" />

    <int:channel id="ftpChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `fixed-rate="10000"` so it will poll every 10 seconds. Fixed rate means every 10 seconds; if the download takes 7 seconds, we'll poll again in 3, then 10, 10, 10 ... until a new file arrives.

`fixed-delay` means the next poll starts that number of milliseconds after the last one finished.

If you want to change the polling rate when no more files are found, you can use a smart poller [documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling).

For convenience, a `SimpleActiveIdleMessageSourceAdvice` is provided, as described in that documentation.